# How do you allocate size to a pointer array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, pass-by-reference

Just learning about call by reference. It's a basic program:

1. I've a null pointer array `A` & array_size initlized to 0
2. I've a function `arrayInput(...)` with arguments `*A` & `*array_size`
3. Goal of this function is to store size input from user to `array_size` & then allocate that size to the above array.

```c
void arrayInput(int *A, int *size) {
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", size);

    // allocate size to A
    A = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(*size));  
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int *A, array_size = 0; // pointer array since I want to allocate the size later
    arrayInput(A , &array_size);
    
    printf("%d, %d", array_size, sizeof(A));
    return 0;
}
```

**Actual Output:**

```
Enter the size of the array: 5
5, 8
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Enter the size of the array: 5
5, 20
```

So why isn't it allocating memory to the array?

Comment: Also `sizeof(A)` is `sizeof(int*)` - which is determined at compile time. You cannot use `sizeof` to find out the size of a pointed to array

Comment: @3rdgrade-dropout, `arrayInput(A , &array_size);` passes a copy of the value of `A` to `arrayInput()` - which is itself trouble because `A` has not yet been assigned.  Anything `arrayInput()` does does not change `main()`'s `A`.  Instead, pass the _address_ of `A`, so `arrayInput()` has a place to put the value of the allocated pointer.